# jQuery.lazy() plugin not working on images loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

The lazy plugin works fine for the initially loaded elements but doesn't work for images loaded via AJAX despite having the code in done function of the AJAX call.

Here is my code for lazy loading images

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("img.lazy").lazy({
        effect: "fadeIn",
        effectTime: 1000
    });
});
```

Here is my AJAX call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loadmore-dj').on('click', function() {
        $('#loadmore-dj').hide();
        $('#loadmore-dj-gif').css( "display", "block");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/loadmore/dj/",
            data: {
                'slug': $('.dj_slug').text().trim(),
                'song_rank': $("#dj_song_list").find('.song_block').length
            },
        }).done(function (response) {
            $(response).appendTo($('#dj_song_list')).hide().fadeIn(1000);
            playOneAudio();
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("img.lazy").lazy({
                    effect: "fadeIn",
                    effectTime: 1000
                });
            });
            $('#loadmore-dj').show();
            $('#loadmore-dj-gif').hide();
        }).done(hideLoadMore);
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove the inner `jQuery(document).ready(function() {...})` wrapper from your `.done` callback; it's not needed.

Comment: Is this the plugin? http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was the missing scroll-event on the AJAX load with lazy by default. Adding the config parameter `bind: "event"` to lazy in my ajax function solved the issue.

```
jQuery("img.lazy").lazy({
    effect: "fadeIn",
    effectTime: 1000,
    bind: "event"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it solved it! Was wondering why nothing was working.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.lazy` plugin is called before the `fadeIn` is complete. Try this --

```
    }).done(function (response) {
        $(response).appendTo($('#dj_song_list')).hide().fadeIn(1000, function() {
            playOneAudio();
            jQuery("img.lazy").lazy({ // don't need document.ready twice
                effect: "fadeIn",
                effectTime: 1000
            });
            $('#loadmore-dj').show();
            $('#loadmore-dj-gif').hide();
            hideLoadMore(); // don't need two .done() callbacks.
        });
    });
```

Comment: I just tried this, it didn't work. However, if I click on the button that calls the AJAX function before the initial images are loaded, the images loaded via AJAX are lazy loaded.

Comment: I'm trying to create a JSFiddle but since it involves an AJAX script, I'm having an hard time figuring out how to do that.